# Adding a key to Nissan NATS system

Tags: nissan, key, security

Is there any way I can purchase / add a key to a Nissan NATS based system other than getting charged through the nose by a dealership?  My car is a 99 Nissan Almera.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for your region, but where I am there are several locksmith/key shops able to cut and program the blank key for a fraction of the cost.

Comment: Specifically for a NIssan NATS based security system?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes : I was with a friend when he inquired about a duplicate key for his '03 Maxima (NATS-based) - they had the blank keys in stock and offered the ability to reprogram it to match the car. The only thing they needed was the original key.

Comment: Keep in mind this is still going to cost you more than a normal key. One of my friends bought a 2015 corolla(Canada). The dealer wanted $400 for another key. He was able to find a locksmith and get a key, but it sill cost him $250. Which is outrageous.